# Substring portion of a text in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Kindly let me know how to extract only

```
IMIS Event - BITWN1802
```

part from the below text (leaving T1 or T1 S1).

I have tried replacing blank spaces with `_` (underscore symbol) to find its `charindex` and so I can use the `charindex` position of the last `_` and to substring it, but it is not working that way.

```
SELECT 
    CHARINDEX('_', (REPLACE([Code], ' ', '_')), 4)
```

[image]

Expected result :

[image]

Your help is appreciated

Comment: Don't post images for sample data, post sample data as text, please.

Comment: What's the *key* element here? - you've not really explained. I.e. I could *imagine* that we need to find a code composed of 5 characters followed by 4 digits and keep it and everything to the left. But that's just one of an almost *infinite* number of patterns I can spot in your sample and expected result. I.e. "just keep the first 22 characters of the text" *also* fits.

Comment: @Larnu: Sure Mate, from next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try like this-

```
CREATE TABLE sts
(
    Vals VARCHAR(200)
)
GO

INSERT INTO sts VALUES
 ('IMIS Event - BITWN1802 ')
,('IMIS Event - BITWN1802 T1 T2')
,('IMIS Event - BITWN18023 T1 T2')
,('IMIS Event - BITWN1801 T1 T2')
,('IMIS Event - BITWN1802 X')
,('')
,(NULL)
GO

SELECT IIF(a<>0,SUBSTRING(Vals,CHARINDEX('IMIS Event - BITWN', Vals , 0),CHARINDEX(' ', Vals , a)),Vals) Vals
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        IIF(CHARINDEX('IMIS Event - BITWN', Vals , 0)>0, CHARINDEX('IMIS Event - BITWN', Vals , 0) + LEN('IMIS Event - BITWN')
        ,0) a
    FROM sts
)x
```

OUTPUT

```
Vals
------------------------------
IMIS Event - BITWN1802 
IMIS Event - BITWN1802 
IMIS Event - BITWN18023 
IMIS Event - BITWN1801 
IMIS Event - BITWN1802 

NULL

(7 rows affected)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the fixed length of characters from the beginning, you can use the [`LEFT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), so the query will be:

```
SELECT LEFT([Code], 22) AS [Code]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (Data varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @Table
SELECT 'IMIS Event - BITWN1802 T2'      UNION ALL
SELECT 'IMIS Event - BITWN1802 T1'  UNION ALL
SELECT 'IMIS Event - BITWN1802 T1 S1'

SELECT Data,
      CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Data,0,CHARINDEX('-',Data)-1),' - ',SUBSTRING(ReqData,0,CHARINDEX(' ',ReqData))) As ReqData
FROM
(
SELECT Data, LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Data,CHARINDEX('-',Data)+1,LEN(Data))) As ReqData
FROM @Table
)dt
```

Result

```
    Data                            ReqData
-------------------------------------------------------
IMIS Event - BITWN1802 T2       IMIS Event - BITWN1802
IMIS Event - BITWN1802 T1       IMIS Event - BITWN1802
IMIS Event - BITWN1802 T1 S1    IMIS Event - BITWN1802
```